# Pipelining Athena query after ETL from glue crawler

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-athena, aws-glue

I have data that is coming into an S3 bucket and I would like to run a query on it every hour. The data comes in as a JSON. I crawl it, run a job on the data to transform it to ORC format, and crawl it again to create a table that's faster for queries than the original JSONs (as they are deeply nested). I'm trying to query the data with Athena. I have managed to link the previous steps together using Lambda and cloudwatch events.

The problem here is that the last crawler is supposed to create new tables instead of just partitions of the same table, so the table name is not known prior to running the list of jobs. I found that you can listen for the creation of a new table and the completion of a crawler, but the log for the end of a crawler's run doesn't contain the name of the new table created (using [Amazon's Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/EventTypes.html#glue-event-types)). Is there a way to get this table name dynamically and query it using Lambda or Athena? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why not invoke lambda from glue job after crawler completes? Table name is folder in S3 bucket in which you stored orc data. Since it is done in glue job, I believe you already have folder name which you can pass to lambda from glue job.